# How can I use an already open IE with VB Script? GetObject is not working

Tags: vbscript

Below is the code block i used to open a new window. I tried using **GetObject** in place of **Create Object** as below. But did not work.

```
Set IE = GetObject("","InternetExplorer.Application")
```

'

```
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://msn.com"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

Set ElementCol = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Link In ElementCol
    If Link.innerHTML = "News" Then
    Link.Click
    WScript.Sleep(6000)
Exit For
End If
Next

IE.navigate "https://msn.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses Explorer which used to do the internet.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Do 
    Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
    Count = 0
    For Each window in AllWindows
msgbox  window.locationname
'        window.refresh2 3
        Count = Count + 1
    Next
    If Count = 0 then Exit Do
    Wscript.sleep 5000
Loop
```